# Mediation: nonsignificant b pathway only when looking at c'

Tags: r, regression, mediation

Per the title, my question concerns how to interpret a standard Baron & Kenny (1986) mediation output. My results are essentially the following:

- Pathway c (DV ~ IV): significant
- Pathway a (M ~ IV): significant
- Pathway b (DV ~ M): significant
- Pathway c' (DV ~ IV + M): nonsignificant

However, when looking at the output for pathway c' containing both the mediator and IV as predictors, my mediator is now nonsignificant despite being significant in the output for pathway b.

Does this matter for mediation? Or, so long as pathway b is significant, then it does not matter if the mediator is now nonsignificant in the output for pathway c'?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to abandon the Baron and Kenny (1986) approach in its original form. If you are wedded to normal theory (and if your sample is reasonably large) you would need something like the Sobel test to determine whether your indirect path (ab) is significant. However, as scholars have demonstrated at least 20 years ago, the sample distribution of ab is not normal; thus, a bootstrapping approach is much preferred. In R use "mediation: R Package for Causal Mediation Analysis" by Tingley et al. This way you can test directly whether the indirect effect ab (in the R mediation package called: ACME) is reliable or not.

Comment: That's helpful as I am using mediation! Am I predominantly interested in ACME and ADE? Such that, if the former is significant, then we can assume some mediation (full or partial)? And if the latter is significant, then we might assume the direct effect is significant, and would suggest partial mediation (if ACME is significant)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: All correct. You are not missing anything.